# Nested interfaces: X does not implement Y (Wrong type for Z method)

Tags: go, interface

In one package I have an interface `Repository` that has a method `GetReporter` that returns an interface `Reporter`. This is used by a function `Execute` that takes a `Repository` and gets its `Reporter` via the `GetReporter` function.

In another package I have a struct `GithubRepository` that has a method `GetReporter` that returns a `GithubReporter`.

In a third package I want to call the `Execute` function out of package #1 with a `GithubRepository` instance.

I am trying to have package 1 and 2 independent of each other, without one importing something from the other. The 3rd package should combine the first two.

Golang returns:

```
cannot use githubRepository (type GithubRepository) as type Repository in argument to Execute:
    GithubRepository does not implement Repository (wrong type for GetReporter method)
        have GetReporter(string) GithubReporter
        want GetReporter(string) Reporter
```

Code:

```
package main

// Package #1

type Repository interface {
  GetReporter(string) Reporter
}

type Reporter interface {
  ChangeStatus(string) error
}

func Execute(r Repository) {
  // Do something with the repository
}

// Package #2

type GithubRepository struct {
}

type GithubReporter struct {
}

func (repo *GithubRepository) GetReporter(sha string) GithubReporter {
 return GithubReporter{}
}

func (reporter *GithubReporter) ChangeStatus(status string) error {
  // Change the status
  return nil
}

// Package #3

func main() {
  githubRepository := GithubRepository{}
  Execute(githubRepository)
}
```

Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/ph0sZnyAC5I

Comment: `GithubReporter` does not implement `Reporter`. The expected method is `ChangeStatus(string) error` whereas `GithubReporter` has `ChangeStatus() error`

Comment: @Marc Right, I missed that when copying the example. Corrected version still returns same error message.

Comment: `func (repo *GithubRepository) GetReporter(sha string) Reporter {
 return &GithubReporter{}
}`

Comment: The method signatures also don't match in for `GetReporter`. As the error message tells you, it needs to return a `Reporter`.

Comment: @har07 @Marc Yes, I could do `func (repo *GithubRepository) GetReporter(sha string) Reporter { return GithubReporter{} }`, but then the second package would need to import `Reporter`. I am trying to have package 1 and 2 independent of each other.

Comment: Can you use comment? Which struct/methods belongs to which package

Comment: @aerokite added above.

Comment: I am trying to have package 1 and 2 independent of each other. This is not possible in this case. @mxinden

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was impossible to make two package independent in such a case. However, with go1.9 and its type alias, this can be done.

First, as go proverbs say, [A little copy is better than a little dependency](https://go-proverbs.github.io/). You should copy the part of definition of `Reporter` to package B, and change the signature according to it: `func (repo GithubRepository) GetReporter(sha string) Reporter`.

Yet the compiler won't understand that the two interface is the samething. But with the help of [type alias](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations), it can be worked around. Change both definition `type Reporter interface {...}` to `type Reporter = interface {...}`. And it will compile now.

Comment: Auctually with earlier go versions, it can still be done, but much, much uglier.

Comment: What about `Import Dot`?

Comment: @aerokite In which package are you trying to import what as dot? Anyway, I would advice strongly against doing so since neither does it break dependency, nor does it provide anything for good.

Comment: See my answer. Edited

Comment: @aerokite So what's wrong with the orignal import? It is much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GithubRepository` and `GithubReporter` as value receiver as you have not create variable as pointer. And return interface in method `GetReporter`

```
func (repo GithubRepository) GetReporter(sha string) Reporter {
 return GithubReporter{}
}

func (reporter GithubReporter) ChangeStatus(status string) error {
  // Change the status
  return nil
}
```

Hope this will help.

See in action: https://play.golang.org/p/Gugm3LetqHU

If you have interface in different package, these is no need to do special things, just point to that interface with package.

In package A

```
package A

type Repository interface {
    GetReporter(string) Reporter
}

type Reporter interface {
    ChangeStatus(string) error
}

func Execute(r Repository) {
    r.GetReporter("report:r").ChangeStatus("status:s")
}
```

In package B

```
package B

import (
    "fmt"
    "test/A"
)

type GithubRepository struct {
}

type GithubReporter struct {
}

func (repo GithubRepository) GetReporter(sha string) A.Reporter {
    fmt.Println(sha)
    return GithubReporter{}
}

func (reporter GithubReporter) ChangeStatus(status string) error {
    // Change the status
    fmt.Printf(status)
    return nil
}
```

May be you can try [Import Dot](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#import-dot)

Comment: Yes, but then package #2 would need to import `Reporter` from package #1. But I am trying to have package 1 and 2 independent of each other.

I will add that to the question above.

Comment: @mxinden, is it?

Comment: @mxinden, can you understand now?

Comment: Would you mind adjusting your example to the above mentioned three packages?

In your example package B imports `Reporter` from package A, which I am trying to not do. I am doing that, so that package A is not coupled to package B, or the other way around. Only the third package combines the two.

Comment: No. You can't do this in this organization.

Comment: You need to return Reporter. In this case, you need to import package A.

Comment: You can use another package.